# Stop job instead of retrying for particular exceptions in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using [default restart strategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/restart_strategies.html) for my jobs and it works fine in case of issues that possibly might be resolved after some time (no network, out of memory, Kafka unavailable etc.) However, there are some exceptions that usually mean bug in the code (e.g. NullPointerException or any other unhandled one), and in such cases I don't want to apply any restart strategy, as any number of restarts won't resolve the issue.

Is there any way to stop a job from inside a job in such cases despite configured strategy?

Comment: It's not supported for now...

Answer (score 2):

I think Flink currently does not support what you try to achieve. But One potential solution is to flip this around.

1. Set the restart strategy to `no retry`.
2. catch the exception that you think that will be resolved after some time (for example, network blip) and retry in place
3. for other failure cases, throw to stop the job

Comment: Right, I've also considered what you propose, but my thinking is that for OutOfMemoryError (or other serious issues with network or disk) I'd rather prefer doing external restart than my own code catching and doing something with them.

Comment: true. for our workload and use case, we chose to fail on any unhandled exception. We made a good effort to automate the restart process for Flink to make this less painful

Comment: How do you automate restarting Flink? What kind of scripts do you have? What APIs do they use?

Comment: good questions. to restart, you need info about most recent checkpoint or savepoint (for RocksDB backend, you can resume from checkpoint). The automation I wrote is done through Fabric + fink management command + S3 CLI.